# What does the X Potion do?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I used the x potion but all it did was rename me Player-346 temporarily. What does that mean?

The recipe is:

- 1 empty potion
- 1 poison potion
- 1 confusion potion
- 1 invisibility potion
- 1 instant countdown potion
- 1 suicide potion
- 1 cookie potion
- 100000 gold bars
- 100000 iron bars

Answer (score 2):

It just changes your name to Player , it's pretty pointless actually.

There is no leaderboard system involved with the numbers.

Comment: This seems to be the author of the game, making this about as an authoritative answer as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it just means you are the 346th player to make Potion X, I myself am Player 210 from making Potion X.

I have yet to figure out what this number actually means, but for all we know its a ranking for a leaderboard of some sort.