# What is the secret potion used for?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I've made secret potion, now I'm wondering what you do with it, or does it have no use to it in the current version.

Comment: ...drink it and find out, perhaps.

Comment: You can't drink it when you're in battle or anywhere else.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate, the secret Potion is called X Potion: Answer from Author here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221849/what-does-the-x-potion-do